# Как создать систему ping'а всех устройств в системе?

Tags: linux, сокет, ping

Пишу backend. Мне необходимо отправлять команды от пользователей на устройство. Однако как мне сделать проверку того, что устройство (это любое устройство, например умная пивоварня) онлайн и желательно, чтобы это было наиболее эффективно.

У меня такой вариант: на python создать socket сервер, к которому по порту, например 49223, будут подключаться устройства. И раз в 5 секунд отправлять им какое-нибудь сообщение. Если ответ пришел, тогда устройство онлайн, если нет, то соответственно устройство не онлайн. В дальнейшем эта информация записывается в базу в столбец is_online.
Если я буду использовать систему с socket, то мне будет под каждое устройство выделять поток, не слишком ли это будет тяжело для сервера, если например устройств будет 100 и более?

Использую базу данных clickhouse.

Предложите свои варианты, напишите комментарии, как мне сделать лучше?

Comment: широковещательное udp сообщение от сервера, кто из клиентов получил - шлёт udp ответ

Comment: @PavelGridin  то есть, как я писал использовать socket для отправки сообщения. А почему udp? Ведь, если это сообщение не дойдет до устройства, то оно будет считаться выключенным. А в tcp мы уверены, что сообщение дойдет, если оно дойдет.

Comment: а почему не дойдёт, если оно включено? udp быстрее запрос-ответ, а с tcp жди пока таймауты сработают. Подождал 100-200 мсек ответов и считай всех сразу опросил

Comment: @PavelGridin большое спасибо за совет!

Comment: почему бы просто не использовать утилиту `fping` ? например команда `fping -a -q < ip.txt` выдаст список всех доступных ip-адресов что указаны в файле `ip.txt`

Comment: @user501383 адреса устройств могут находиться вне моей локальной сети + необходимо проверять каждое устройство, что есть в базе. Если это те же умные устройства, то после переподключения к домашней сети они могут получить другой ip адрес, соответственно список уже будет неактуален.

Comment: @FroggerProgger 1) `fping` подходит как для локальных так и для внешних ip-адресов 2) есть проблема вывести ip-адреса из базы в файл ? да в принципе можно и не через файл, а через stdin или даже просто записать все ip в переменную и передать в утилиту 3) когда меняется адрес в базе разве сложно обновить файл или переменную с ip-адресами ?

Comment: @user501383 в 2х двух пунктах вы абсолютно правы. А на счет третьего. Не будет ли получаться так, что если во внешнюю сеть отправляются, то будет записываться ip роутера через который отправлено, а не ip самого устройства. Так как при отправке запроса в интернет роутер запаковывает ip устройства, от которого идет запрос в свой ip и отправляет в интернет, откуда уже приходит ответ на роутер, а он сам распаковывает и отправляет уже на устройство.

Comment: @FroggerProgger непонятно, у вас для каждого устройства  который вы собрались проверять есть выделенный `ip-адрес` ?

Comment: @user501383 нет, выделенного ip нет, но как это связано?

Comment: @FroggerProgger в таком случае ping/fping не подойдёт, хотя это был бы самым простым вариантом

Comment: @user501383 понятно, спасибо больше за потраченное время!

Answer (score 1):

устройства вешай на mqtt брокер - пусть он держит коннекты. не стоит заниматься лоулевелом если пишешь большую систему.

проверять онлайн надо не по флагу "is_online" а выдавать устроству комманду, на которую оно ответит - я тут.

не критичные задания можно складывать в очередб на том же mqtt. когда устройство вернется - оно выполнит задание.

Comment: Через mqtt я планировал делать отправку команд. Вопрос даже задал:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1554862/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-mqtt-mosquitto

Если я буду проверять онлайн оно или нет, тогда не получится заранее знать, что онлайн и в том же мобильном приложении тогда не будет видно, онлайн устройство или нет. В таком случае будет ли актуально поднять топик для ping'а устройств?

Comment: Можно гнать этот пинг в mqtt

Comment: благодарю за подсказку. Пока что надумал такую структуру 

room/№ комнаты/actions
room/№ комнаты/events
room/№ комнаты/ping

actions - здесь будут появляться задания от сервера (клиент отправляет серверу, сервер на топик)
events - здесь будут ответы от устройства. 
ping - тут раз в промежуток времени будет появляться "ping", на которое устройство будет отвечать например "OK" - так будем понимать, что устройство онлайн.

Однако возник вопрос. Если я использую php, тогда мне стоит написать сторонний сервер, который будет принимать ping и обновлять информацию?