# Настройка mqtt mosquitto

Tags: php, linux, mqtt

Нужно, чтобы сервер динамически создавал топики.
Предположим, что у нас есть дом **`home`** и нужно, чтобы устройства, которые относятся, к этому **`home`** подписывались на его топик и постоянно ожидали сообщений.
Однако таких **`home`** может быть несколько, например **`home_1`**, **`home_2`**, **`home_3`**.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы php сервер создавал топики для этих **`home`**. При этом мне нужно, чтобы топик не закрывался удалялся. даже, если все устройства выключились и в данный момент не подключены к топику.

При этом хотелось бы, чтобы шла авторизация устройства из базы данных clickhouse. Однако модуля для авторизации с clickhouse я не смог найти.

Пример необходимого топика: home/{номер дома}/actions.